# Totally ramified extension with respect to local vs global

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, ramification

Let $F$ be a number field and let $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathsf{Spec} \: \mathcal{O}_F$. We have a non Archimedean valuation $\nu_\mathfrak{p}\colon F\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, given by $\nu_p(x):=\mathsf{card}(\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p})^{\mathsf{ord}_\mathfrak{p}(x)}$.
$F_\mathfrak{p}$ is completion with respect to valuation   $\nu_p(x)$.

If $F$ and $K$ are number field and $F/K$ is finite galois extension.

My question is,

> Does $F_\mathfrak{p}/K_\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified implies
> $\mathfrak{p}$ is totally ramified in $F/K$ ?

I think this kind of statement holds if we add (although may be we need to add some condition).
Reference(pdf, book, etc) is also appreciated.

Comment: No. Consider $\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}$ and the prime ideal $(2+i)$. It’s totally split, so has trivial residue field extension, thus the local field extension is totally ramified (in fact, trivial).

Comment: The (discrete) valuation is $\mathsf{ord}_\mathfrak{p}(x)$ while $\mathsf{card}(\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p})^{\mathsf{ord}_\mathfrak{p}(x)}$ is the non-archimedian absolute value.

Comment: If we add additional condition that   $[F_p;K_p]＝[F:K]$(extension degree does not change under), is my claim true ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3,7^{1/3})/\Bbb{Q}$ and $\mathfrak{p} = (\zeta_3-2,7^{1/3})$